# Login works in Django Rest Framework but not on frontend

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following views:

**login_view**:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login_view(request):

    try:
        user_data = request.data
        username = user_data["username"]
        password = user_data["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            serializer = UserSerializer(user)
            return Response(
            {
                "user":serializer.data,
                "login": True
            })
        else:
            return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except:
        raise Http404
```

**logout_view**:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def logout_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

and fetch function on **frontend**:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/',{
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "username": values.Username,
          "password": values.Password
        })
        }).then((response) => {response.json().then(data => {                  
        if(response.ok){
            setError('');           
            console.log(data);
      } 
      else{
        setError('');
        setError('Invalid Username or Password');  
      }
    })});
  };
```

and the following problem:

When I try to sign in on frontend I get an expected response:

```
{
  user: {id: 4, username: 'Tester_1', date_joined: '2021-12-02T22:38:29.323393Z', trust_index: 0}
  login: true
}
```

but my user is not logged in Rest Framework and I can't use logout view on Frontend:
[After login on Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3JfD.png)

When I use Rest Framework panel for login, everything works fine, user is logged in and I can use logout view:
[After login in Rest Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDkWz.png)

I've been struggling with this for a while. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your global code but it seems you are trying to create a session based login/auth system, bringing the autogenerated drf web panel approach to your front. In this separated structure (front and back) this is not the best approach, at least you build a weird structure where Django encapsulates your front and manage sessions etc.

A probably better way is to use jwt token generation/authentication. Where you authenticate (from front) using a user and password but you receive (from back) a token that you have to store locally (local storage, to emulate a session).

In each request you pass the token in the header and if everything is fine (valid token) drf do the stuff.

I use Simple JWT (https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Really simple.

Here is an example of **urls.py** for auth endpoints:

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView
website_v1 = 'website/v1/'

urlpatterns = [
    path(f'{website_v1}login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path(f'{website_v1}login/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

And in front, Axios (https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) is a good js library to automatize the token passing in data fetching using interceptors.

Good Luck!

Comment: I considered this solution but I need access to some data from the backend even without login. Is it possible in this approach to not use JWT with specific GET views?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes it's possible! in DRF views you could assign the permission class to all the views, or a specific viewset, or specific actions in a viewset. You could assign `AllowAny` for everyone access. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/